# Contract added with contract-out is not enforced

Tags: racket

I need an explanation of why this 'contract-out' does not work.
It should only return positive value but it still accepts a negative value. Can anyone explain? thank you.

```
#lang racket


(struct account (balance))

(provide (contract-out
     [balance (-> account? number?)]
     [deposit (-> account? positive-num? account?)]))

(define new-account (account 0))

(define (positive-num? n)
  (cond [(not (number? n)) #f]
    [(> n 0) #t]))

(define (balance acc)
  (account-balance acc))

(define (deposit acc amt)
  (account (+ (account-balance acc) amt)))

(displayln (balance (deposit new-account -10)))
```

Comment: There is another version I have tried was '[deposit (-> account? (and/c number? positive?) account?)]. Also it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your program as written.

First of all, your `positive-num?` predicate is wrong. Try it on a negative number—you won’t get back `#f`. Your implementation will make `(positive-num? -10)` produce `#<void>` (since no `cond` clauses match), which is not `#f` and is therefore truthy. You can rewrite the body of `positive-num?` to simply `(and (number? n) (> n 0))`, which is both clearer and actually correct, but you could also scrap the custom `positive-num?` predicate entirely and just use the contract `(and/c real? positive?)`.

The second issue with your code is more subtle. When a value is given a contract, the contract is attached on a *contract boundary*. The contract is enforced whenever the value is used outside the contract boundary, but it isn’t enforced inside the contract boundary. This is because, inside the contract boundary, you’re using the value directly, not the value with a contract attached.

When you use `contract-out`, the contract boundary is the module providing the identifier. Outside of the module, the contract is enforced, but inside the module, it isn’t. Therefore, since your whole program is within a single module, the contracts are never relevant.

To see this in action, try a program consisting of multiple modules:

```
#lang racket

(module bank racket
  (provide (contract-out
            [balance (-> account? number?)]
            [deposit (-> account? (and/c real? positive?) account?)]
            [new-account account?]))

  (struct account (balance))

  (define new-account (account 0))

  (define (balance acc)
    (account-balance acc))

  (define (deposit acc amt)
    (account (+ (account-balance acc) amt))))

(require 'bank)
(displayln (balance (deposit new-account -10)))
```

Since the contracted definitions have been moved into a separate submodule, and since the call to `deposit` is outside that submodule, the above code raises a contract violation:

```
deposit: contract violation
  expected: a number strictly greater than 0
  given: -10
  in: the 2nd argument of
      (->
       account?
       (and/c real? positive?)
       account?)
  contract from: (anonymous-module bank)
  blaming: anonymous-module
   (assuming the contract is correct)
  at: unsaved-editor:6.13
```

If you *want* the contract to be enforced within the same module, you need to use a form that creates a more fine-grained contract boundary than `contract-out`. One such form is [`define/contract`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/attaching-contracts-to-values.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fregion..rkt%29._define%2Fcontract%29%29), which creates a boundary between the definition itself and everything outside the definition’s body:

```
#lang racket

(struct account (balance))

(define new-account (account 0))

(define/contract (balance acc)
  (-> account? number?)
  (account-balance acc))

(define/contract (deposit acc amt)
  (-> account? (and/c real? positive?) account?)
  (account (+ (account-balance acc) amt)))

(displayln (balance (deposit new-account -10)))
```

Now the contract violation will be signaled even though the use and definition are in the same module.

For more details on contract boundaries and why you might wish to choose one form over the other, see [Contracts and Boundaries](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/contract-boundaries.html) in The Racket Guide.